# Usb not detected by computer

Tags: usb

I was using my usb drive. Suddenly electricity turned off and my computer turned off. Later when I open my computer and run my usb it was being detected by the computer. Tell me is it the hardware problem or other problem?

Comment: The answer that Anto gives you may solve problems with the USB subsystem. If that does not help it may be a case of your HD having errors, ranging from simple software errors to the disk being fried. In that case, search SuperUser - there's plenty of posts from people having HD problems.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Solutions :-

1. Shut down and restart

   In some cases, just restarting your windows operating system resolves the issue. Just shut down your computer in the normal way and unplug the power supply for a minute or two. If you are not able to do that (for eg, if mouse and keyboard both not working) then you don’t have any choice but to switch off the power button. After a couple of minutes, switch on the power supply and boot your PC in normal way. Once you have restarted your PC, obviously the USB ports and the motherboard also get rebooted. The microprocessor will reload the drivers and hopefully you should not get the “USB Device Not Recognized” error again.
2. Uninstall and then reconnect the USB device

   If the above trick doesn’t work, you may try this option.
   a. Click Start, type Device Manager in the Search box. Now click on Device manager.
   b. In the device manager, find the USB device from the list of hardwares. For example, if the USB device that stopped working was an external hard drive, you have to click “Disk Drives” from the list of hardware.
   c. Right-click the USB device having issue and click Uninstall.
   d. After the drive is uninstalled, unplug the USB device.
   e. Wait for a minute and then reconnect the USB device.
   The driver should automatically load.
   f. Now check for the USB drive in Windows Explorer.
3. Reinstall USB controllers
   If the above two methods don’t work, follow this method.
   a. Click Start, then type device manager in the Search box and then click Device Manager.
   b. Expand the Universal Serial Bus controllers. Right click a device and click Uninstall. Repeat for each device.
   c. Once complete, restart your computer. Your USB controllers will automatically install.
   Hopefully your issue should be resolved. In worst case, if it’s not resolved, you may have to try installing hotfixes, or install latest updates of the Windows operating system or install motherboard latest chipset drivers.